# Unable to parse DateFrame JSON into C#

Tags: c#, json, jsonparser

I'm unable to parse the JSON file below to the corresponding class. It was exported by pandas' DateFrame. The reason I can't parse it, is because the format is a bit weird. How can I do that?

```cs
private static List<BacktestResult> LoadFromJson(string path)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, path);

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"The data file '{filePath}' was not found.");

    var data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BacktestResult>>(data);

    return deserializedData;
}
```

It works but I want the `Pair` to be parsed without the `/` and SellReason to be parsed as `SellType` (the enum). OpenDate and CloseDate cannot be parsed directly to DateTime, because they have to be converted through the following `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(OpenDate)`.

```cs
public class BacktestResult
{
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitAbs { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal TradeDuration { get; set; }
    public bool OpenAtEnd { get; set; }
    public SellType SellReason { get; set; }
}

public enum SellType
{
    None,
    TakeProfit,
    StopLoss,
    TrailingStopLoss,
    SellSignal
}
```

#### JSON:

https://pastebin.com/KHH2fgm7 (pastebin because it's exceeds the SO limits)

#### Edit:

Thanks to @Panagiotis Kanavos, the JSON now looks like: https://pastebin.com/jNdRC23k. I exported it from pandas as following: `results.to_json(r'dateFrame_json.json', orient='split')`.

```cs
public class BacktestResult2
{
    [JsonProperty("pair")]
    public string Pair { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profit_percent")]
    public decimal ProfitPercentage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profit_abs")]
    public decimal ProfitAbs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("open_rate")]
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("close_rate")]
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("open_date")]
    public long OpenDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("close_date")]
    public long CloseDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("open_fee")]
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("close_fee")]
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trade_duration")]
    public decimal TradeDuration { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sell_reason")]
    public SellReason SellReason { get; set; }
}

public partial class SellReason
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private static List<BacktestResult> LoadFromJson(string path)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, path);

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"The JSON file '{filePath}' was not found.");

    var data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    // results.to_json(r'dateFrame_json.json', orient='split')
    var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BacktestResult2>>(data);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: IMO you have 2 options. One is to deserialzie it using `JsonReader` and assign values by hand and the second one is to use `Dictionary<string, T>` foreach entry on the root object.

Comment: @Mateusz, would you like to type it as an answer?

Comment: Post a *sample* of the JSON string in the question itself. The question makes little sense as-is. There are no dataframes in JSON, only arrays and objects

Comment: The Python code would help as well. [Pandas uses different well-defined layouts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) through the `orient` parameter. Which one are you using? Can you change it to something other JSON libraries can handle?

Comment: @nop what you linked to could be either the `row` or `column` orientation.  Which one did you use? You don't need a JsonReader, although it could improve performance. You could use `JObject.Parse` to parse that JSON string and use eg LINQ to query it, but you still need to know if it's per row or per column

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I can change the python code. It's currently: `results.to_json(r'dateFrame_json.json')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, what `orient` should I use, so I can import it directly?

Comment: Edited the question. It looks better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your whole json file then I would suggest remodeling your datastructures to use `Dictionary<string, T>`.

```
public class BacktestResult
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Pair { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> ProfitAbs { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> OpenRate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> CloseRate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, DateTime> OpenDate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, DateTime> CloseDate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> OpenFee { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> CloseFee { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> TradeDuration { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> OpenAtEnd { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> SellReason { get; set; }
}
```

Then you just have to deserialize it as one object, like such:

```
BacktestResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BacktestResult>(content);
```

---

Test this on [rextester](https://rextester.com/ETZ19187)

Answer (score 0):

The names of the BacktestResult class fields must be exactly the same as the json file fields.